# JavaScript Word Count - Calculation

Tags: javascript

I have a script to count the words in an attachment which works fine.

```
function loadDemo() {

      WordCount.words("file_attach", function(words) {
        document.getElementById("words").innerText = words;
      });


    var elt = document.getElementById("words");
    var words = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;

    words = parseInt(words);

    var tprice = (words /500) * 12;

    document.getElementById("tprice").innerText=tprice;

}
```

I then wanted to calulate a price which is printed in span box below.

The word count is printed to its span, but price is not. Where have i gone wrong in my calculation?

```
<div id="result"></div>
<label for="name"><span>Name</span>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
</label>

<label for="email"><span>Email Address</span>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
</label>

<label for="file"><span>Attachment</span>
<input type="file" name="file_attach" id="file_attach" onChange="loadDemo()" />
</label>

<label for="words"><span>No. of Words</span>
<span id="words"></span>
</label>

<label for="tprice"><span>Price</span>
<span id="tprice"></span>
</label>

<label for="message"><span>Message</span>
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Name"></textarea>
</label>

<label><span>&nbsp;</span>
<button class="submit_btn" id="submit_btn">Submit</button>
</label>
```

Above is HTML of form.

Thanks

Comment: What's WordCount and this `words` function?

Comment: some questions make me a little bit sad

Comment: words and tprice are both span elements. Words works fine, nothing is printed to tprice. words function is linked to an external js script i am using.

Comment: @user69200 Please, don't explain it in the comments. Edit your question - that way you can be more detailed in your explanation. It would would also help a lot if we could see the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript for looking up the words is:

```
var elt = document.getElementById("words");
var words = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].value;
```

but the second line is what you'd use for retrieving values from a select dropdown. The element `<span id="words"></span>` however is not a select element. You need to use:

```
var elt = document.getElementById("words");
var words = elt.textContent;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SKPs6/2/)

As a side note, it's a bit unusual to use `<label>` tags for things that aren't form controls. Specifically there's no point in using the label's `for` attribute to point to a non-input element because they can't receive focus.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Making the changes you suggested gave me 'NaN' inside the tprice span. I noticed that even when i set the value of tprice to 1 (var tprice = 1;), it still does not show in the label.

Comment: Where exactly did you put it? If you have `var tprice = 1; document.getElementById("tprice").innerText=tprice;` it's not possible that it would show `NaN`.

Comment: Ive narrowed the problem to parseInt. It doesnt convert the 'textContent' of words to an integer, are there other ways to convert?

Comment: What is the content? Show some examples.